# Angular 7 Hide bootstrap modal in typscript

Tags: bootstrap-modal, angular2-routing, angular7, mdbootstrap

I want to call (click)="basicModal.hide()" methode of MDBootstrap Modal inside one of my fuctions in my typescript component. I don't know how to access this method from component.

```
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="relative waves-light" (click)="basicModal.show()" mdbWavesEffect>Launch demo modal</button>

<div mdbModal #basicModal="mdbModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myBasicModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" mdbBtn color="secondary" class="waves-light" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()" mdbWavesEffect>Close</button>
        <button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="relative waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the Angular's @ViewChild decorator to target the mdbModal directrive, and then use the hide() method from ModalDirective class.

Please take a look at the below code, there's explained everything:

.html:

```
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="relative waves-light" (click)="basicModal.show()" mdbWavesEffect>Launch demo modal</button>

<div #modal mdbModal #basicModal="mdbModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myBasicModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="md-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" mdbInput>
          <label for="input1">Modal input</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button mdbBtn color="primary" mdbWavesEffect (click)="hideModal()">Hide modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts:

```
 @ViewChild(ModalDirective) modal: ModalDirective;

  hideModal() {
    this.modal.hide();
  }
```

If there will be something unclear, feel free to ask again!