# Want to understand the working of @ViewChild()

Tags: angular

My Question id related to a previous thread answer.
[Angular 7 Hide bootstrap modal in typscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973818/angular-7-hide-bootstrap-modal-in-typscript)

The Solution provided to hide the modal in typescript code was to have the @ViewChild(ModalDirective) modal : ModalDirective access the local reference and then use method hide on that.

But according to my understanding as a beginner to Angular 
@ViewChild('modal') modal : ModalDirective should be used since @ViewChild takes local reference as an argument.
Then why have we passed ModalDirective.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

> The following selectors are supported.

- Any class with the `@Component` or `@Directive` decorator
- A template reference variable as a string (e.g. query `<my-component #cmp></my-component>` with `@ViewChild('cmp')`)
- Any provider defined in the child component tree of the current component (e.g.
  `@ViewChild(SomeService) someService: SomeService`)
- Any provider defined through a string token (e.g. `@ViewChild('someToken')
  someTokenVal: any`)
- A `TemplateRef` (e.g. query `<ng-template></ng-template>` with `@ViewChild(TemplateRef) template;`)

Comment: what is the use case of getting child component provider in parent component.
For example, Any provider defined in the child component tree of the current component (e.g. @ViewChild(SomeService) someService: SomeService)